# Error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier C/C++

Tags: c++, intellisense, extern

Is there a way to define BEGIN_C_CODE and END_C_CODE macros to properly expand?

Platform: Visual Studio 2012

HeaderFile.h

```
#if defined (__cplusplus)
  #define BEGIN_C_CODE extern "C" {
  #define END_C_CODE }
#else
  // Edit: @shathaway mentioned 'The not case is actually included in my code'
  #define BEGIN_C_CODE
  #define END_C_CODE
#endif
```

ProgramFile.cpp

```
#include "HeaderFile.h"
BEGIN_C_CODE
// C Source Code
END_C_CODE
```

In the ProgramFile.cpp, the END_C_CODE registers an Intellisense error:
"this declaration has no storage class or type specifier."

When macro expansions are not used, but using the full wrapper, things work!

```
#if defined (__cplusplus)
  extern "C" {
#endif
// C Source Code
#if defined (__cplusplus)
}
#endif
```

Comment: What if `__cplusplus` wasn't defined?

Comment: #if defined (__cplusplus)
      #define BEGIN_C_CODE extern "C" {
      #define END_C_CODE }
    #else

Comment: The not case is actually included in my code. Since C++ always
defines (__cplusplus) I chose not to include the 'C' compiler case
in the example.

The issue involves the C++ compiler and an Intellisense error.
The debugger shows that both BEGIN_C_CODE and END_C_CODE appear
to be properly defined.  Using BEGIN_C_CODE to start an extern "C"
block and then END_C_CODE to finish the code block, the Intellisense
issues the error: this declaration has no storage class or type specifier.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you getting compile errors, or just intellisense 'errors'?

Comment: It appears to be an Intellisense error appearing in the build error report.  The program segment appears to compile properly, but I don't trust the code because of the reported Intellisense error condition.  Is it SAFE to ignore the Intellisense errors?